# Where can I find better data than yahoo geoplanet or factual's world geographies?

Tags: data, geoplanet, yahoo

Currently I am using Factual's world geographies api to do a location search so if you search london, london england should appear or if you search new york city, new york city will appear.

I am having trouble because there is no filters like population that I can use to sort by the best match.

Here is [factuals data](http://developer.factual.com/world-geographies/). I found a download for geoplanet [here](https://archive.org/details/geoplanet_data_7.10.0.zip) but I can't seem to find any data set with these sorts of filters.

Do I need to find a better data set or am I just not structuring the query correctly?